# Como centrar texto en botón

Tags: html, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de centrar este texto en un boton como puedo hacerlo?

```
<div class="container-sm">
    <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
          <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
              <button class="login100-form-btn" name="registe">Unirse</button>
          </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo con css , con display:flex y justify-content y align-content con valor centre

Comment: Tienes una etiqueta rota. Concretamente la etiqueta form. Las reglas d maquetación que sigue el botón estarán declaradas en algún fichero CSS "linkado" en la página. Ahí es donde se está definiendo la alineación del botón.

Comment: Eso debe ser por que falta codigo, asi como falta el CSS que el tiene, boostrap y demases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías crear una clase CSS aparte y ponerle la propiedad `text-align: center;` o utilizar las clases que da **Bootstrap** por defecto, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/.

Código CSS:

```css
.clasecss{ text-align: center; }
```

Con **Bootstrap:**

```html
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me soluciono el problema.

Comment: A nada, siempre es importante leer la documentación del framework ya que estos de css suelen tener muchas herramientas practicas que nos ahorran esas 4 líneas de estilos css...

Comment: Muchas gracias @David saludos!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ocupa class="text-center" dentro de tu button

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un fichero externo CSS y desde este aplicarlo sobre el botón
aplicando `text-align: center;` y tu texto debería estar perfectamente centrado.

```css
.login100-form-btn{
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
text-align: center ;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ruta/archivo.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-sm">
    <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
          <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
              <button class="login100-form-btn" name="registe">Unirse</button>
          </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```