# Como centrar texto en boton

Tags: html, css

No estoy logrando centrar el texto [**Unete**] en el boton ya he tratado con codigos que vi en internet y aun nada, me podrian guiar con el codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Css

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50; 
  color: white;
}



 <div class="flex-m w-full p-b-40">
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-sm">
                        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <button class="login100-form-btn" name="registe">
                            Únete
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Intenta revisar el html, esta mal, en cuanto al centrado podes utilizar text-align:center en el contenedor del texto, en este caso el boton.

Comment: Hola @Luz, agrega el código suficiente que permita reproducir el mismo botón que tienes en tu proyecto acá en Stack Overflow, de lo contrario, será muy difícil que puedas conseguir orientación. Consulte [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como centrar texto en botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414801/como-centrar-texto-en-bot%c3%b3n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo sencillo, puedes usarlo así:

```html
<button class="login100-form-btn" name="registe" style="width:200px;text-align:center;">Únete</button>
```

Es solo una alternativa pero lo recomendable es darle una clase y usarlo con CSS Algo así:

```css
.txtCenter {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="login100-form-btn txtCenter" name="registe">Únete</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu css está dando estilos a un `input tipo submit`, y no un button, en este caso el texto se coloca adentro, de todas formas si usas button solamente centra el texto, pero si quieres mas ayuda postea el css del botón:

```css
button {
  background-color: #4CAF50; 
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 25px;
}
```

```html
<button class="login100-form-btn" name="registe">Únete</button>
```

Comment: La propiedad `text-align: center` no es necesaria dentro de un `button`. Pues por defecto tiene centrado vertical y horizontal al contenido interior

Answer (score 0):

Añade a tu botón el type, por eso no te funciona

```
 <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn" name="registe">
                        Únete
                        </button>
```

Y cambia el CSS:

```
  button[type=submit] {
tu codigo anterior;
text-align: center;
}
```